# How do I break or delete a symbolic link?

Tags: files, symbolic-link

I created a link using the following command.

```
sudo ln -fs /usr/share/icons/Cyclone/cursor.theme etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
```

I now want to delete this link, as it seems to create some problems. Is this done by deleting the cursor.theme file? What are the steps to achieve a complete deletion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
unlink /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
```

You may also be interested in update-alternates

```
update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme
```

Comment: what do you mean by update-alternates ???is it like updating the link???

Comment: That command will give you a menu to select your mouse cursor theme.

Comment: Note that, while this answer is correct, [`unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/unlink.1.html) is not limited to removing symbolic links. It will also delete ordinary files, same as [`rm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rm.1.html). In particular, users should be aware that `unlink` is *in no way safer* than the widely used `rm` command.  (Unlink simply ["avoids the bells and whistles of the more commonly-used `rm` command"](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#unlink-invocation).)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
sudo rm /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
```

Comment: what are you talking about this is one of the system files if i delete it will crash something.

Comment: The system file is at /usr/share/icons/Cyclone/cursor.theme , and will be unaffected. The link is at /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme , and will be removed.

Comment: You asked how to delete a symbolic link. That's how. :) The system file is not changed, but the symbolic link, destroyed.

Comment: bodhi.zazen shows you how to choose a new one with 'update-alternatives' I bet it even changes the value of the symlink.

Comment: I'm late to the party.. but one way you know this works without affecting the source file is that it's not specifying recursion with -r. You can't delete a directory with rm unless you use -r. Sudo won't even remove it.